# Access dynamic port number in Webpack

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, webpack, electron

I'm building an electron/nodejs/react application that will run on a users localhost (e.g. `localhost:8080`).

I'm using [Portfinder](https://www.npmjs.com/package/portfinder) to locate a free port and run the application on that port.

```
portfinder
    .getPortPromise()
    .then(port => {
        app.listen(port, function() {
            console.log("Server started on localhost:" + port + ", Node ENV " + app.get("env"));
        });
    })
    .catch(err => {
        //Could not get a free port, `err` contains the reason.
    });
```

In the React app, I need to access this port number to send `http` requests back to the node server.

Is there a way to access this dynamically created port # in React or Webpack outside of using env variables in `package.json` or `.env` file?

Comment: While this may not be an optimal solution - from security perspective - you may want to save the new port number in a cookie from backend and then fetch it in the frontend.

Answer (score 0):

If the same server is used for serving client and backend APIs, then you can use relative routes (`/api/getData`). The client will hit the same server.

If your backend is hosted on a different server, then you need to pass the information to client manually.

Comment: I've tried that, with this electron app relative routes end up with `file://` in the path so it needs to include the complete path.